# How to deploy a Qt3D application on Mac OS-X

Tags: macos, qt, deployment

If I deploy the demo-app sphere.app on OS-X with

macdeployqt sphere.app

and try to start it with

sphere.app/Contents/MacOS/sphere

I get the error message

file:///Users/dev/src/qt3d-1.0-src/bin/sphere.app/Contents/Resources/qml/sphere.qml:42:1: module „Qt3D“ is not installed
     import Qt3D 1.0

otool –L sphere.app/Contents/MacOS/sphere shows, that the frameworks are correctly deployed:

sphere.app/Contents/MacOS/sphere:
    @executable_path/../Frameworks/Qt3D.framework/Versions/1/Qt3D (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    @executable_path/../Frameworks/Qt3DQuick.framework/Versions/1/Qt3DQuick (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    @executable_path/../Frameworks/QtDeclarative.framework/Versions/4/QtDeclarative (compatibility version 4.8.0, current version 4.8.3)
    @executable_path/../Frameworks/QtScript.framework/Versions/4/QtScript (compatibility version 4.8.0, current version 4.8.3)
    @executable_path/../Frameworks/QtCore.framework/Versions/4/QtCore (compatibility version 4.8.0, current version 4.8.3)
    @executable_path/../Frameworks/QtSvg.framework/Versions/4/QtSvg (compatibility version 4.8.0, current version 4.8.3)
    @executable_path/../Frameworks/QtGui.framework/Versions/4/QtGui (compatibility version 4.8.0, current version 4.8.3)
    @executable_path/../Frameworks/QtSql.framework/Versions/4/QtSql (compatibility version 4.8.0, current version 4.8.3)
    @executable_path/../Frameworks/QtXmlPatterns.framework/Versions/4/QtXmlPatterns (compatibility version 4.8.0, current version 4.8.3)
    @executable_path/../Frameworks/QtNetwork.framework/Versions/4/QtNetwork (compatibility version 4.8.0, current version 4.8.3)
    @executable_path/../Frameworks/QtOpenGL.framework/Versions/4/QtOpenGL (compatibility version 4.8.0, current version 4.8.3)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/OpenGL (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/AGL.framework/Versions/A/AGL (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 7.9.0)
    /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 830.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 125.2.11)

Does onybody know how to fix this? Is this a Qt bug or did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the application is not able to find any of the Qt frameworks and only reports the first one which happens to be Qt3D.
Can you confirm that the Qt3D Frameworks exist

`@executable_path/../Frameworks/Qt3D.framework/Versions/1/Qt3D`

Here @executable_path is path to your binary which would most probably be sphere.app/Contents/MacOS/sphere. So Qt3D should exist at

```
sphere.app/Contents/Frameworks/Qt3D.framework/Versions/1/Qt3D
```

If not you can copy from Library Framework path to create above Path